# javascript to disable /enable a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below syntax which unchecks a checkbox.

```
$('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');
```

`h12_1` is the name of my checkbox.

How do I disable the checkbox so it cannot be checked? similarly how do I enable the checkbox again?

Something like this:

```
 $.post('get_as_12', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {
 alert(result[0]) ;

      if(result[0] > 0) {
          $('#h12_1').attr('checked','enabled');
          $('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');
       } else {
          $('#h15_1').attr('disabled');
          $('#h15_1').removeAttr('checked');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For disabling you should use `disabled` attribute or property (the latter is **preferrable**):

```
$("#h12_1").attr("disabled", "disabled");  // removeAttr("disabled") to enable
// or
$("#h12_1").prop("disabled", true);        // false to enable
```

Comment: Just 2 secs late!! so u get +1

Answer (score 1):

To disable checkbox, use  disabled attribute.

```
$("#h12_1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To enable it back again use removeAttr().

```
$('#h15_1').removeAttr('disabled');
```